# SelectList in Partial View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, partial-views, html.dropdownlistfor, selectlistitem

I'm new to ASP.NET MVC and I'm trying to get a dropdown list in a partial view to work. I did search on this web site and others, but I didn't find a suitable answer to my app. I guess the best way to explain my problem is to show you my code.

In advance, I apologize for the english errors, this is not my first language.

Here is the ViewModel for user creation :

```
namespace AppliSuiviPV.ViewModels
{
public class CreateUserAppliViewModel
{
    [Display(Name = "Numéro d'utilisateur")]
    [Key]
    public int UserAppliID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Nom")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Le nom est requis")]
    public string UserAppliNom { get; set; }

    // some other attributes ...

    // clé étrangère
    [Display(Name = "Rôle")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Le rôle est requis")]
    public int UserRoleID { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> UserRoles { get; set; }
}
}
```

I have two partial views in my index : a list and a modal for creation.

The Index (here I just remove the Javascript) :

```
@model List<AppliSuiviPV.ViewModels.ListeUtilisateursViewModel>

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Liste des utilisateurs";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml"; // layout avec le menu
}

<!-- La modale -->
<div class="modal fade" id="CreateUserAppliModal" tabindex="-1"   role="dialog" aria-labelledby="CreateUserAppliModalLabel">
<div class="modal-dialog modalCreateUserAppli" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h3><strong>Nouvel utilisateur</strong></h3>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-body" id="form-container">
            @Html.Partial("_CreateUserAppli", new AppliSuiviPV.ViewModels.CreateUserAppliViewModel())
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
</div>

<div id="userAppliList">
@Html.Partial("_UserAppliList", Model)
</div>
```

Here is the partial view in which I want the dropdown list (for UserRoleID) :

```
@model AppliSuiviPV.ViewModels.CreateUserAppliViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateUserAppli", "UserAppli", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "form-createuser" }))
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div id="result"></div>
<div class="form-horizontal">

    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserAppliNom, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserAppliNom, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", id = "nomUser" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserAppliNom, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- ... -->

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserRoleID, "Rôle", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.UserRoleID, Model.UserRoles, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserRoleID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Au moins un champ non renseigné -->
    <div id="missingData">
        <div class="alert alert-danger"> <strong>Tous les champs sont obligatoires</strong></div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <button type="button" id="createuser-reset" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Annuler</button>
            <button type="submit" id="createuser-submit" name="createuser-submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-left:5px;">Valider</button>               
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
}
```

And finally the controller action to display the partial view :

```
// Création Utilisateur par la modale
    // GET
    public ActionResult CreateUserAppli()
    {
        // population de la liste des rôles
        var lesRoles = (from s in db.UserRoles select s).ToList();

        // création de l'objet User qui contiendra la liste des rôles
        CreateUserAppliViewModel userAppli = new CreateUserAppliViewModel
        {
            UserRoles = lesRoles.Select(x => new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = x.UserRoleID.ToString(),
                Text = x.UserRoleLibelle
            })
        };

        return PartialView("_CreateUserAppli", userAppli);

    }
```

The problem is : when I run the app, I get the error message (translated)

> The ViewData element with the key UserRoleID is type System.Int32 
>   but should be type IEnumerable<SelectListItem>.

And the index doesn't display. For information, it all worked out fine before I add all the code for `userRoleID`.

Would anyone have a lead please ?

Comment: `@Html.Partial()` does not call you controller method - it just renders the view so `UserRoles` is `null`. You need `@Html.Action()` to call the method.

Comment: Thank you Stephen ! I will try that !

Comment: @Html.Action() instead of @Html.Partial() was the solution ! Thank you again !